# CompizConfig : Fire animation not found even after install compiz-extras

Tags: 14.04, compiz, plugins, animations

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on my pc and I have installed the necessary compiz plugins to get animations running such as compiz-plugins-extra,compiz-plugins, but I am unable to find 'Fire' animation for closing a window.

I checked on net, and 1 or 2 people had the same question, but no solution mentioned works.

I have other animations, but not the 'Fire' one, does anyone know how to install it.

Kindly let me know. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The burn animation is part of a plugin called Animation Addon. Since Compiz 0.9.8, that plugin has been disabled in the Compiz build system to complete OpenGL ES support, meaning that when Compiz is built, it's built without that particular plugin. For that reason, you won't find it in any recent packages.

If you build Compiz from source, you can edit the plugins/CMakeLists.txt file and change

> `set (COMPIZ_DISABLE_PLUGIN_ANIMATIONADDON ON)`

to

> `set (COMPIZ_DISABLE_PLUGIN_ANIMATIONADDON OFF)`

But it won't do you any good as the build will fail.

I suppose you could try cannibalising the required files from an old compiz-plugins-extra binary: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/x11/compiz-plugins-extra

I've no idea whether that will work or not but it might be worth messing around with if you really want that plugin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try it in free time, unfortunately I can't do that in office machine as it might screw the UI. I will accept your answer if it works after trying out.